# How can I collect bug data to be submitted on another machine?

Tags: bug-reporting

I know I can file a bug report on the local machine by running `ubuntu-bug`. But what about when I have a bug on another computer elsewhere so that it's not convenient to get to it physically to file a report there? Can I use Ubuntu's bug reporting tools to gather data about the bug remotely, transfer that data to my local machine and submit a bug report here with the data from the other system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "[Filing bugs when off-line](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs#Filing_bugs_when_off-line)" section of the bug reporting community help can be applied here:

> First, on the target system, gather the information in a file:
>
> 1. For a bug report about a system crash:
>
>    `apport-cli -p <package name> --save bug.crash`
> 2. For a bug report about any other issue:
>
>    `apport-cli -f -p <package name> --save bug.apport`
>
> You will need to answer a few questions, which will vary depending on
>   which package the bug report is about. Relevant system information,
>   including the package name, is then saved on the target system, in the
>   current directory. The extension indicates if it is a crash report or
>   another kind of report. If you decide to rename the report file,
>   please keep the `.apport` or `.crash` extension.
>
> When the file is ready, copy it to the system you intend to use for
>   filing the report. There you can then file the report:
>
> `ubuntu-bug -c <apport_file.extension>`